# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on storing images in sqlite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap, out-of-memory

I want to store images in my database. Also I want to check that if the image and title is already in the database. If so, it will not add them to the database. This is my class.

**Attractions**

```
public class Attractions extends ListActivity {
DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
List<Contact> contacts;
ContactImageAdapter adapter;
int ctr, loaded; 
int [] landmarkImages={R.drawable.oblation,R.drawable.eastwood,R.drawable.ecopark,R.drawable.circle};
String []landmarkDetails = { "Oblation", "Eastwood", "Ecopark", "QC Circle"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attractions);
    ctr  = db.checkContact(landmarkDetails[loaded]);



    // get image from drawable

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");


    for(loaded=0; loaded <landmarkDetails.length;loaded++){

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                landmarkImages[loaded]);


        // convert bitmap to byte
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
        Log.d("Going to load images", "Image "+ loaded);

        Log.d("Goind to load objects", "loading");

        if(ctr == 0){
            Log.d("Nothing Loaded", "Loading Now");
            db.addContact(new Contact(landmarkDetails[loaded], imageInByte));}
            Log.d(landmarkDetails[loaded], "Loaded!");
            image.recycle();
    }
    loadFromDb();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.attractions, menu);


    return true;
}

public void loadFromDb(){
    // Reading all contacts from database
            contacts = db.getAllContacts();
            for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
                        + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.d("Result: ", log);
                //add contacts data in arrayList
                imageArry.add(cn);

            }
            adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,
                    imageArry);
            ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

}


}
```

It works fine on the emulator, but I tried testing on my S4 and then after 3 tries of going to this class, it forced stop. I tried it with usb debugging and the logcat showed `java.lang.outofmemoryerror` . The logcat pointed the error in my contactimageadapter.

**ContactImageAdapter**

```
public class ContactImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
 Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
   // BcardImage data[] = null;
    ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
    public ContactImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ImageHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ImageHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Contact picture = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(picture._name);
        //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

        byte[] outImage=picture._image;
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
       return row;

    }

    static class ImageHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

And pointed to this line `Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);`

I have little (almost none) knowledge on managing images and storing them. I also enable `android:largeHeap` but still force closes on multiple tries. I hope someone can help me solving this issue, or at least show me a different way of storing text and images to sqlite db. Many thanks!

Comment: Generally it is  recommended to store file in App Directory (External) and maintain File Path in Database as necessary Inserting image and retrieving image from database is complex operation

Comment: Follow instructions in http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: How big is the image?   Perhaps you need to resize it and compress it before storing.  As an amateur photographer then I know that you can compress a jpg to at least 80% with no noticeable impact on the quality, in most cases also 70% (assuming you don't do it multiple times on the same image).  You currently have 100% quality ratio.  If you resize and compress, this can make a big difference on the size needed and hence memory required.

Comment: Check all the images having how much mb.if it is bigger, you will get oom error

Comment: Adding images or big blobs into any database, no matter if you're using SQLite, Oracle or MS SQL Server, is a terrible idea that will lead to huge performance penalties in all tables of the database.

Comment: best practice is, store image in directory and use image absolute path indatabase

Comment: A note: make sure you're closing your input/output streams. GC won't pick those up efficiently if you don't. Can cause memory issues. Probably not your issue here, but it might be compounding the problem.

Answer (score 10):

You have multiple places where whole image (assuming it is big) keeps in memory:

1. Contact object has it. All loaded images are in imageArry which is instance level variable.

   ```
   public class Attractions extends ListActivity {
       DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
       ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
   ```
2. in `ContactImageAdapter.getView` method you create another copy of image as BMP in holder object and pass it out of method.
   So, at some point you do not have enough memory to keep all of them. Also I sure that `decodeStream` needs some more memory to perform.

After all it is not predictable when each new holder created in `getView` will be cleaned by GC. 
Usually for such situation when object created as new in some method, then passed back to the calling method, that object will be collected only by Full GC.

So, as "Software Sainath" said, do not store images in database…
and do not keep them in memory either.

P.S. Then provide to the view a link to the external image file. That also will save time to load a view. Image will be in cache and if user at least once got it, it will not pass through the network again.

I guess images there are not frequently change them self. another image of Contact will be another file…

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an answer to the somewhat similar problem some while ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030770/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-converting-over-100-strings-into-to-byte-arrays/38031308?noredirect=1#comment63503330_38031308) is the link that you can check. The problem is in the approach of saving the images into the database, you should not be doing this. Instead, write the images as files on the phone memory and use it further.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't store Image to Sqlite Database eventually, you will ran into out of memory error after three or five image saved to database. It's not the best practice, maximum memory allocated for field in a row in sqlite is less than 3mb, be aware of this.
2. Instead of saving Images to database, Keep the images inside your app folder, save the path to the Database.
3. Your are loading your image as it is to your Image adapter. Let's say your image is 1280x720 resolution and 2mb in size, it will take the same space in your memory Heap.

You can either scaledown your image and load it as bitmap to your Adapter ImageView like this.

Before loading your image as Bitmap get it height and width.

```
//Code read the image and give you image height and width.it won't load your bitmap. 


  BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(your_image_url,option);
                int image_original_width = option.outHeight;
                int image_original_height = option.outWidth;
```

Now to scale down your Image you have to know the ImageView width and height. This is because we are going to scale down the image matching the imageview with pixel perfection.

```
int image_view_width = image_view.getWidht();
 int image_view_height = image_view.getHeight();
 int new_width;
 int new_height;

float scaled_width;
 if(image_original_width>image_view_width)
{     //if the image_view width is lesser than original_image_width ,you have to scaled down the image.  
     scale_value =(float)image_original_width/(float)image_view_width; 
     new_width = image_original_width/scaled_value;
     new_height = image_orignal_height/scale_value
}
else
{
  // use the image_view width and height as sacling value widht and height;
      new_width = image_view_width;
      new_height = image_view_height;
}
```

Now Scale Down your bitmap and load it like this.

```
  // this will load a bitmap with 1/4 the size of the original one.
   // this to lower your bitmap memory occupation in heap. 
   BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   option.inSampleSize = 4;
   Bitmap current_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_url,option);
   Bitmap scaled_bitmap =      Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(current_bitmap,new_width,new_height,true);
holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(scaled_bitmap);
//release memory occupied by current_bitmap in heap, as we are no longer using it. 
current_bitmap.recycle();
```

If you want to understand a little more about Bitmap and memory view this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA&index=1&list=LLafgz0wVndcp3KICDn5v8Ew).

If you don't want to handle rescaling bitmap by yourself. you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library which does the same.

I have written an article about using Picasso to load image in listview, which will help you to start, if you are looking to use picasso.

http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2015/11/picasso-android-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use the quick garbage collection eligible reference type while loading the images from the network

```html
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  
public class MemoryCache {
    private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());
  
    public Bitmap get(String id){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }
  
    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }
  
    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't store Image to Sqlite Database. It's not the best practice.
2. Instead of saving Images to database, Keep the images in a storage, but if you want to keep them private then keep them inside your app folder and save the path to the Database.
3. Use one of the well known libraries like http://square.github.io/picasso/ or https://github.com/bumptech/glide, they offer great help with memory issues and also some cool transition effects.
   I recommend using Glide because it works very well on device with low memory restrictions