# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while converting over 100 Strings into to byte arrays

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, arrays, android-glide

Firstly, I understand questions regarding `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` and Bitmaps have already been asked numerous times before. I have also checked out the  [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) page.

**My use case:**

I am storing two different sized Bitmaps as Strings in an SQLite database. The first size of the Bitmaps is 50% of the screen width, and the second size is 100% of the screen width.

I am using a RecyclerView which displays the images in ImageViews which are either 50% or 100% of the screen width, so the Bitmaps being loaded **are no bigger than they need to be, and they are appropriately sized before the images are retrieved from the Database.**

I am also loading the Bitmaps using an AsyncTask.

I have over 180 different items in the RecyclerView so I have a total of over 360 Bitmaps (i.e. numberOfimages * theDifferentSizesOfEachImage) being created. I am coverting the String versions of the images into byte arrays via this code:  `byte [] byteArray = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);`

**The Problem**

The Activity was able to load over around 170 different images without encurring the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, unless I restarted the same Activity (e.g. load the Activity, then recreate the Activity by clicking on it again in the Navigation Drawer and then repeating that process)  and incurred the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` whilst converting the Strings into byte arrays.

I am converting the byte array to a Bitmap using the **Glide** library using the following code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(context).load(byteArray).asBitmap()
 .dontTransform().dontAnimate().skipMemoryCache(true)
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(-1, -1).get();
```

**My Question in a nutshell**

How do I avoid the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` occurring whilst am I converting the Strings into byte arrays?

**Note**

After creating a Bitmap using Glide I am calling recycle() on the given Bitmap and then setting it to `null`.

I am also already using `android:largeHeap="true"` in my Android Manifest

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Here is how I am creating the Bitmap Strings:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,100, baos);
        byte [] b =baos.toByteArray();
     String bitmapString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: why dont you compress it before storing it...

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you are referring to compressing the Bitmaps, I already am doing that, I edited my question and you can see how I compress the Bitmaps before converting them into Strings

Comment: "I am storing two different sized Bitmaps as Strings in an SQLite database" -- why? Store them as files, with filenames in the database. Or, store them as BLOB columns, to at least eliminate the `String` conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am storing two different sizes of the Bitmaps because I use both different sizes of the images. Would storing them as files and storing the filenames in the database, or storing the images in BLOB columns help to avoid the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. If both options would help to avoid the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` which option would be the most memory efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would suggest you to drop your approach, this would just not work with large set of image and you are already putting to much work on your thread to handle. One should never store image like that in the sqllite.
You should just convert your bitmap to a file having unique name or could be same (depends upon your use case) then you can just save this file inside the app directory and save the file path in database. Here is some code to help you.

```
File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(getActivity(), MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
```

private File getOutputMediaFile(Context context, int m) {

```
    File mediaStorageDir = context.getFilesDir();

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Fade", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());

    File mediaFile=new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath()+File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".JPG");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Now you have the file and now you can just store the file path in the database and when its needed you can always get your file from the storage using glide. This would also make your database fast to queries.

This way you wont need any changes in gradle or anywhere else. Try this.

Comment: Thank for your response. I will either try and save the images as Files as byte arrays if that'll solve the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Do you think that saving the images as files and then converting the files into images is more memory efficient than saving the images as byte arrays in a BLOB column in the SQLIite database and then converting those byte arrays to Bitmaps?

Comment: Yes sir, also you are not converting any file to image. Image saved in the storage is itself a file. You are now going to just give the glide library the direct path of your file and leave the caching and showing of image in your view to the glide which is does very efficiently. Just give it a shot and practise this solution always. What are you were doing earlier is just a waste of memory. By keeping the images as file inside apps folder wont reveal it the gallery hence working exactly like you want it to.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try saving the images as files, and if that solves the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` then I'll accept your answer