# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.database.CursorWindow.getString in android

Tags: java, android, database, bitmap, base64

I have create static database and this database add base 64 string for image this image is large size i have run my app while getting error for database to get string how to solve it.

I m new in android programming...

**Database**

```
public List<People> getAllPeople() {

    List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_PEOPLE, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (cursor != null) {
                String peopleImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_IMAGE));\\ This line getting error
                String categoryId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY_ID));
                String peopleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_NAME));
                String peopleId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID));
                int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(STATUS));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_MONTH));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_DATE));
                String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_YEAR));
                String peopleDetail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_DETAIL));


                People people = new People();
                people.setId(peopleId);
                people.setPeopleName(peopleName);
                people.setPeopleImage(peopleImage);
                people.setStatus(status);
                people.setMonth(month);
                people.setDate(date);
                people.setYear(year);
                people.setPeopleDetail(peopleDetail);
                people.setCategoryId(categoryId);

                peoples.add(people);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", e.getMessage());
    }
    return peoples;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(people.getPeopleImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length, options);
    if (bmp1 != null) {
        holder.ivPeopleImage.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
    }
```

Comment: so why are you using `Base64` then?

Comment: I have already add base64 encode string in static database..@pskink

Comment: do you know what base64 is for?

Comment: I don't know?@pskink

Comment: Because simple to use and get to string and after decode so i m use base64@pskink

Comment: Any other option to solve this qu?

Comment: its not advisable saving image on sqlite, you can try saving it as files then keep the unique directory as string on sqlite. maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030770/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-converting-over-100-strings-into-to-byte-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think it is a good idea to store image in database. Saving them in Base64 makes your solution even slower, you need to do encoding and decoding every time you manipulate them. My suggestion is that you save image files on storage media and keep URI in database, it is faster and more manageable.

If you really need to do it in your way for whatever reason... Try to set `android:largeHeap="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

UPDATE:

```
  private static final String FOLDER="/MyApp/";  
  private static String saveBitmapToSd(Bitmap bmp, String fileName){
        String pngName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+FOLDER+fileName+".png";
        FileOutputStream fos= null;
        boolean success=false;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pngName));
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,fos);
            success=true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "saveBitmapToSd: ", e);
        }
        finally {
            if(fos!=null)
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "saveBitmapToSd: ",e );
                }
        }
        if(success)
            return pngName;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

This is the method to save bitmap to sd card and return a path string.
I just wrote a very simple demo app, you can check it out here.
[Demo App](https://github.com/Meowzz95/PicAndDb)

Comment: Any tutorial for save image in file and get URI in database@MiDaa

Comment: but my all Images are static not dynamic that's fix so how can i put all images in db plz explain in details@MiDaa

Comment: hello MiDaa this demo is dynamic save images in database but my tasks is   already define people images so how can i put images in database using file plz help me..

Comment: @User6829548 Okay.. I don't really get what you are trying to say here.Where are your static images? SD card?

Comment: not sd card.I have put base64 String in image column in sqlite browser direct and get all image using database helper class@MiDaa

Comment: @User6829548 where are your original files? Are you saying that you want to copy your base64 images in SQLite to the file system programmatically?

Comment: My database Original file in assets folder ya i have save base64 string save in database programmatically..@Midaa

Comment: @User6829548 you can try to read your images form database and save as files using the method above one by one (do not read all at same time to prevent OOM). Btw I really don't understand your English... maybe because I am not a native speaker either..

Comment: sorry for my bed english@MiDaa

Comment: Do you understand in my questions yes or no?

Comment: @User6829548 This is what I have understood: your images are in and only in your SQLite database file, you want to read images from it and save them using the method which stores images on sd card and paths in database. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes in my above my questions getAllPeople method to get all images using model class and those all image set id wises how can all images save in file system not one by one..

Comment: @User6829548 Sorry....I really can't understand. Why must you take your images from the DB file instead of starting over to use the new method to save?